# Web Application not visible in Artifactory after deployment. Asks for login credentials

Tags: maven, jsp, artifactory

I have deployed a very basic web app to JFrog that I created using Maven. It has a basic JSP file that says "Hello World" I deployed a .war file manually. After deployment, I was able to see the link like

```
 localhost:8082/artifactory/MyWebApp/
```

But, when I hit it, it redirects me to 8082 and asks for a username and password which I never set up. I tried the login name and password but this does not seem to work. I have not used any authentication in my application. Kindly help

[image: Login Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I resolved it. As it was a new installation, I generated a new token and gave it permission to access. I was thus able to access the path and download the artifact.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a permission issue to me. Generate a new token with proper access. Should work.